# abnormal margin in my facebook iframe application

Tags: facebook

the size of my application isnt the full 760 pixels, i am getting about 750.

i based my application on this template: http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development/

iframe size is set to resizable.

Comment: could it be possible there is a scrollbar that is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was there was a default margin on the  i had to set the margin and padding to 0.